# Angular AngularFire2 checking if user isAdmin

Tags: angular, angularfire2

These are the errors:

```
http://d2kt888p40scfz.cloudfront.net/js/ista.js#bpiopmneeadfapifejkfpahpljkicpik Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
core.js:3121Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
http://d2xvc2nqkduarq.cloudfront.net/zr/js/adrns.js#WDCXWD5000AAKX-75U6AA0_WD-WCC2EALU9690U9690 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
core.js:1673ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.auth.user$.switchMap is not a function
TypeError: this.auth.user$.switchMap is not a function
    at AdminAuthGuard.push../src/app/admin-auth-guard.service.ts.AdminAuthGuard.canActivate (admin-auth-guard.service.ts:17)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:2799)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:5)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call (map.js:18)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:24)
    at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:29)
    at AdminAuthGuard.push../src/app/admin-auth-guard.service.ts.AdminAuthGuard.canActivate (admin-auth-guard.service.ts:17)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:2799)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:5)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call (map.js:18)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:24)
    at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:29)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1673
core.js:1673ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.auth.user$.switchMap is not a function
TypeError: this.auth.user$.switchMap is not a function
    at AdminAuthGuard.push../src/app/admin-auth-guard.service.ts.AdminAuthGuard.canActivate (admin-auth-guard.service.ts:17)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:2799)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:5)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call (map.js:18)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:24)
    at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:29)
    at AdminAuthGuard.push../src/app/admin-auth-guard.service.ts.AdminAuthGuard.canActivate (admin-auth-guard.service.ts:17)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:2799)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:5)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call (map.js:18)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:24)
    at MergeMapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call (mergeMap.js:29)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1673
```

Source code:

```js
user.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { updateClassProp } from '@angular/core/src/render3/styling';
import { AppUser } from './models/app-user';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }
  
  save(user: firebase.User){
    this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
    });
  }
 get(uid:string): FirebaseObjectObservable<AppUser>{
   return this.db.object('/users/' +uid);
 }
}
```

```html
admin-auth-guard.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private userService: UserService) { }
 
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean>{
   return this.auth.user$
      .switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid))
       .map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin);  
    }


}
```

please point me in a right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use rxjs 6, you cannot chain observable transformation operators as before, you should use pipe, like:

```
import {switchMap, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.auth.user$.pipe(
  switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid)),
  map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin)
);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I have used your suggested code the switchMap error is solve but still when I click on my manage order menu as an admin it's not showing the message admin-order works. and chrome also showing couple of errors like failed to load resource: net: error  name not resolved error @Amir Arbabian please help.

Comment: it is showing error in index.d.ts file on this line:   type SpyObjMethodNames<T = undefined> = T extends undefined ? (ReadonlyArray<string> | {[methodName: string]: any}) : (ReadonlyArray<keyof T> | {[P in keyof T]?: ReturnType<T[P] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? T[P] : any>});   i am new to this language m not understanding whats going wrong why it is not checking admin is true or not